# InversifyJS : Error when retrieving object from container

Tags: node.js, inversion-of-control, inversifyjs

I am using InversifyJS to setup some kind-of dynamic binding and running it on NodeJS. The problem I have is that I get errors, but without messages and only a stacktrace.

The `Main` class

```
export class Main {
    public static getCalculator(config: string): Calculator {
        try {
            var container: Container = new KeyFeatureContainer(config).getContainer();
            debugger;
            // error here !
            return container.get<Calculator>(TYPES.Calculator);
        } catch (error) {
            debugger;
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This class calls the `KeyFeatureContainer` with a `json` string, used to configure all the bindings (in a sort-of dynamic way), and then retrieves the container.

The `KeyFeatureContainer` class

```
export class KeyFeatureContainer {
    private _container: Container;

    public constructor(config: string) {
        var jsonConfig: any[] = JSON.parse(config);

        this._container = new Container();
        this._container.bind<Calculator>(TYPES.Calculator).to(KeyFeatureCalculator);

        for (var i = 0; i < jsonConfig.length; i++) {
            if (jsonConfig[i].active) {
                this.parseConfigKeyFeatures(jsonConfig[i].id);
                this.parseConfigParams(jsonConfig[i].params);
            }
        }
    }

    public getContainer(): Container {
        debugger;
        return this._container;
    }

    private parseConfigKeyFeatures(id: string): void {
        var keyFeatureContainerModule: ContainerModule = rootContainer.get<KeyFeatureContainerModule>(id).getContainerModule();

        if (keyFeatureContainerModule != null)
            this._container.load(keyFeatureContainerModule);
    }

    private parseConfigParams(params: Array<{ name: string, value: any }>): void {
        for (var param of params)
            this._container.bind(param.name).to(param.value);
    }
}
```

This class receives the `json` configuration and loads, following an ID, a `ContainerModule` which contains the binding between the interface and the concrete implementation. The `rootContainer` specifies the `ContainerModule` to retrieve following an ID.

The `rootContainer`

```
var rootContainer: Container = new Container();

rootContainer.bind<KeyFeatureContainerModule>(KEYFEATURES.DrugHoliday).to(DrugHolidayContainerModule);
rootContainer.bind<KeyFeatureContainerModule>(KEYFEATURES.MissingDay).to(MissingDayContainerModule);

export default rootContainer;
```

And the related `ContainerModule`s (the second one is identical, just the PARAMS that are different for each)

```
@injectable()
export class MissingDayKeyFeature implements KeyFeature {
    @inject(PARAMS.MissingDayParams.NbIntakesLimit)
    private _nbIntakesLimit: number;

    @inject(PARAMS.MissingDayParams.ExtraParamA)
    private _extraParamA: any;

    @inject(PARAMS.MissingDayParams.ExtraParamB)
    private _extraParamB: any;

    public init(): void {
        console.log("init() at MissingDay");

        console.log("nbIntakesLimit = " + this._nbIntakesLimit);
        console.log("extraParamA = " + this._extraParamA);
        console.log("extraParamB = " + this._extraParamB);
    }

    public calculate(): void {
        console.log("calculate() at MissingDay");
    }

    public finish(): void {
        console.log("finish() at MissingDay");
    }
}

@injectable()
export class MissingDayContainerModule implements KeyFeatureContainerModule {
    public getContainerModule(): ContainerModule {
        return new ContainerModule((bind: interfaces.Bind, unbind: interfaces.Unbind) => {
            bind<KeyFeature>(TYPES.KeyFeature).to(MissingDayKeyFeature);
        });
    }
}
```

And finally, the `ServiceIdentifiers` used to setup the whole (separated files)

```
let TYPES = {
    KeyFeature: "KeyFeature",
    Calculator: "Calculator"
}

export default TYPES;

let PARAMS = {
    DrugHolidayParams: {
        NbDaysLimit: "nbDaysLimit",
        ExtraParamA: "extraParamDHA",
        ExtraParamB: "extraParamDHB"
    },
    MissingDayParams: {
        NbIntakesLimit: "nbIntakesLimit",
        ExtraParamA: "extraParamMDA",
        ExtraParamB: "extraParamMDB"
    }
}

export default PARAMS;

let KEYFEATURES = {
    MissingDay: "MissingDayKeyFeature",
    DrugHoliday: "DrugHolidayKeyFeature"
}

export default KEYFEATURES;
```

Finally the `JSON` input (formatted for convenience)

```
[{
        "id": "DrugHolidayKeyFeature",
        "active": true,
        "params": [{
                "name": "nbDaysLimit",
                "value": 3
            }, {
                "name": "extraParamDHA",
                "value": "DHA"
            }, {
                "name": "extraParamDHB",
                "value": "DHB"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": "MissingDayKeyFeature",
        "active": false,
        "params": [{
                "name": "nbIntakesLimit",
                "value": 0
            }, {
                "name": "extraParamMDA",
                "value": "MDA"
            }, {
                "name": "extraParamMDB",
                "value": "MDB"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I use a simple `Test` script just to output the values and see if all bindings are done correctly

```
import { Main } from "./Main";
var json: string = *json above*;
Main.getCalculator(json).calculate();
```

But I end up with this error

```
Error
<     at _createSubRequests (D:\Projects\226RD\nodejs\phantomjs_2016_by_DM\final\node_modules\inversify\lib\planning\planner.js:106:19)
<     at Object.plan (D:\Projects\226RD\nodejs\phantomjs_2016_by_DM\final\node_modules\inversify\lib\planning\planner.js:125:5)
<     at D:\Projects\226RD\nodejs\phantomjs_2016_by_DM\final\node_modules\inversify\lib\container\container.js:205:37
<     at Container._get (D:\Projects\226RD\nodejs\phantomjs_2016_by_DM\final\node_modules\inversify\lib\container\container.js:198:44)
<     at Container.get (D:\Projects\226RD\nodejs\phantomjs_2016_by_DM\final\node_modules\inversify\lib\container\container.js:163:21)
<     at Function.getCalculator (D:\Projects\226RD\nodejs\phantomjs_2016_by_DM\final\transpiled\KFCalc\Main.js:9:30)
<     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\226RD\nodejs\phantomjs_2016_by_DM\final\transpiled\KFCalc\Test.js:4:13)
<     at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
<     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
<     at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
```

There is no clue about what is happening, and I can't figure out what I have done wrong. I can't `get<Calculator>` nor `get<KeyFeature>`, but if I do :

```
container.isBound(TYPES.Calculator) // returns true !!!
```

and same applies for all bound items.

Thank you for any pointers, I'm out of ideas.

```
+-- @types/node@7.0.2
+-- inversify@3.0.0
+-- reflect-metadata@0.1.9
+-- typescript@2.0.10
```

EDIT : Forgot the `KeyFeatureCalculator`

```
@injectable()
export class KeyFeatureCalculator implements Calculator {
    // multi-injection of bound key features
    private _keyFeatureCalculators: KeyFeature[] = [];

    public constructor(@multiInject(TYPES.KeyFeature) keyFeatureCalculators: KeyFeature[]) {
        this._keyFeatureCalculators = keyFeatureCalculators;
    }

    public calculate(): void {
        console.log("calculate() at KeyFeatureCalculator");

        for (var calculator of this._keyFeatureCalculators) {
            calculator.init();
            calculator.calculate();
            calculator.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, all my files (or almost) import `inject, injectable` from `inversify` and also import `reflect-metadata`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error resolved : For those who didn't pay attention, each `KeyFeature` object has its properties injected, and their types are `number` or `any`. Since the values are retrieved from my `JSON`, they are typed as `any` and thus the compiler doesn't warn me that the binding `bind(xxx).to(yyy)` requires to be a `newable` element !

So, in my example, the `yyy` was something like `3`, which is a number and thus not boundable. I changed to `bind(xxx).toConstantValue(yyy)` and everything works !